How can I perform accurate vector search for complex objects?
I have objects that have many attributes, example:
item = {
 'id': 123,
 'name': 'Keyboard',
 'price': 12,
 'url': 'example.com',
 'description': 'a keyboard that etc...',
 'details': {
    'color': 'white',
    'foo': 'bar'
  }
}

I want to vector search these items using a user query. For example:
INPUT: red mouse cheaper than 25$
OUTPUT: id of a mouse which details suggest it is red, and its price is less than 25$
I tried to embed them by stringifying the JSON object then feed it to an embedder, but to no avail. The similarity search is not bad but rarely meets the expectations. I am looking for a more accurate method of getting the objects I want. I thought of embedding each attribute alone but that will take too much space. Any ideas?
My embedding Model is sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2

Did you make any headway on this? I'm on a similar pursuit.

@KalenGi The method that got me the best accuracy for my use case (although not perfect) is to run the whole row of data into a text summarizer. I used OpenAI API to summarize the name, description, and details. Then I use the summary to compare between items. It proved to be much better than embedding the whole row without any processing.

Thank you very much @AbdulmohsenA for this insight.
